# fast pixels processing using np.isin and np.where [issue]

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I am new with python and image processing. I am trying to find a list of given RGB values in an input image using np.isin and np.where ( i wanted to avoid nested looping over all the pixels ).
So, here is the input and output

Input: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx3ck.jpg

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzOSK.jpg

I am using the following code -

```
fliterlist = [
    [244,240,255],
    [253,239,255],
    [255,234,249],
    [255,230,245],
    [255,229,243],
    [255,228,242]
]
# actual list has more than 100 elements

def imageTest(img,count=0):

    outImg = np.zeros(img.shape,dtype=np.uint8)

    posArray=(np.isin(img,bb)).all(axis=2)
    outImg[np.where(posArray)] = [255,255,255]

    outname = './fast/imageTest_'+str(count)+'.jpg'
    outputlist[outname]=outImg

    return
```

For some reason, I am not getting the output as expected. I mean if I use a double nested loop for iterating over all the pixel, I get the desired result. But here it looks like np.isin is giving me a different outarray.
Please help me identify the issue.

Here is the example idea which works perfectly -

image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYIKe.jpg

Comment: can you specify, what you are trying to do? What I can understand you are trying to threshold an image.

Comment: Let just say there is an image.and i need to find out specific RGB values in it. For instance lets just say i am looking for all the pixels with value [255,0,0]. So output image is basically black image with only those pixels marked as [255,255,255]. Does it help ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the inrange function of opencv, as follows:

```
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower_range, upper_range)
```

I understand you want to find a particular pixel, so adjust range accordingly. 
In my experience, whatever task you will try to accomplish its better to use a range of pixel, so that will be beneficial. But later is up to you.